# Writing to a seismic cube in ocean using using 3D array

Tags: ocean, petrel

I read all the samples from a seismic cube using

```
int NumI = InputSCube.NumSamplesIJK.I;
                int NumJ = InputSCube.NumSamplesIJK.J;
                int NumK = InputSCube.NumSamplesIJK.K;
                double[, ,] InputSeismicCubeData = new double[NumI, NumJ, NumK];


for (int i = 0; i < NumI; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < NumJ; j++)
                    {
                        ITrace Trace = InputSCube.GetTrace(i, j);
                        for (int k = 0; k < NumK; k++)
                        {
                            InputSeismicCubeData[i, j, k] = Trace[k];
                        }
                    }

                }
```

After applying Some algorithms I generated output seismic data which is also a 3D array of same size as InputSeismicCubeData

and I worte the data to a cube as

```
using (ITransaction trans1 = DataManager.NewTransaction())
                    {

                        SeismicCollection Sc = InputSCube.SeismicCollection;
                        trans1.Lock(Sc);
                        if (Sc.CanCreateSeismicCube(InputSCube))
                        {
                            SeismicCube NewCube = Sc.CreateSeismicCube(InputSCube, InputSCube.Template);
                            if (!NewCube.IsWritable)
                            {
                                PetrelLogger.ErrorBox("Unable to Write to the Cloned Cube");
                                return;
                            }



                            for (int i = 0; i < NumI; i++)
                            {
                                for (int j = 0; j < NumJ; j++)
                                {

                                    ITrace trace = NewCube.GetTrace(i, j);
                                    for (int k = 0; k < trace.Length; k++)
                                    {
                                        trace[k] = (float)OutPutSeismicCubeData[i, j, k];
                                    }

                                }
                            }

                            trans1.Commit();
                            arguments.OutputSCube = NewCube;
                        }
                    }
```

Code is Compiling and Running but it doesn't makes sense, seems as if all the samples are jumbled. 
Any Help Appriciated

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any issue with the code you have in place. There are some tools in the Ocean API for SeismicCube that may help and make it more performant.

First, have a look at the method GetSubCube( Index3, Index3 ). It creates an in memory portion of your SeismicCube. It has a method, ToArray, that will provide a 3 dimensional array of the cube samples as you are doing. Another method, CopyFrom, will copy samples from a 3 dimensional array to the ISubcube. If the original SeismicCube (the output in your case), is locked, then the ISubCube data values will be placed back into the SeismicCube.

So your processing down through generating your data for the output would be the same. After creating the output cube you would create a ISubCube from (0,0,0) to (numI-1, numJ-1, numK-1). Use the CopyFrom method to copy your output array to the ISubCube and since the output SeismicCube is locked when you created it the data in the ISubCube should be placed in it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I later found that code was all right, the samples were jumbled up because of the MATLAB functions.